# Smooth movement to the clicked element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

How to make a move `div` (#line) to the clicked area (`li`) using jquery?

HTML menu:

```
<div class="floor-switch" id="floors">
    <div class="arrw-up"></div>
    <div id='line'></div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="arrw-down"></div>
</div>​
```

Example of what I want (but now it moves only to the specified distance): http://jsfiddle.net/js6CM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqKx8/)

```
$('.floor-switch li').click(function() {
    $('#line').animate({
        top: $(this).position().top
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you want:

```
$('.floor-switch li').click(function() {
    var clickedElement = this;
    var line = $('#line')[0];
    var movement = clickedElement.offsetTop - line.offsetTop;

    $('#line').animate({
        left: 0,
        top: line.offsetTop + movement
    });
});​
```

Im getting the clicked element in `clickedElement` and the red line in `line`. Then I'm calculating the `movement` that have been done and finally adding that movement to the red line.

I hope it helps!.

Regards.

**Edit**:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jT6kC/).